# Automatically and continually reload an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

This website uses an iframe to vote for 3 separate couples
http://www.bellacollinamansion.com/Bella_Collina_Experience.html

I've discovered that I can reuse the same input information (same captcha in this case) as long as I space my queries out by 10s. Therefore, I can theoretically right click the vote complete frame and just press "reload frame" and it will vote once more without me having to type in a new captcha every time.

I have attempted doing this with my limited knowledge of javascript as follows:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
window.location.reload();
}, 11000);
```

This didn't work and responded with an error:

```
"Missing user information. This form could not be located."
```

I assume it's not using the same action as when I manually reload the frame.

Is there any way to do this other than using a ghetto auto-clicker?

Comment: Using .reload() doesn't include the POST information you posted originally with the new request. That page you linked to isn't working, can I get a proper link?

Comment: Sorry, somehow I must have deleted the L at the end of the link. I fixed it. I'll post it here as well: http://www.bellacollinamansion.com/Bella_Collina_Experience.html

Comment: I would suggest approaching this from a different direction. Like writing something that intercepts the iframe's form's submission, takes the values that would normally be posted, and using AJAX to do it yourself. Then you could reuse that ajax request...